# 'readmemh' not properly reading memory file?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I wrote the following testbench in verilog that writes a file and then reads the values back.

```
  // Verilog Test Fixture Template

  `timescale 1 ns / 1 ps

  module Read_And_Write_File;

  /*Add signals used for verification of the values written in SRAM*/
    integer   handle, channels,index;
   reg [15:0] memory [22:0]; 
    reg [22:0] mem_idx;
    reg [15:0] val;

initial begin
  /*Write the memory file 'SRAM.dat'using the values that are supposed to be in the SRAM after the simulation*/
            handle = $fopen("SRAM.dat");
            channels = handle | 1;
         $display("Generating contents of file SRAM.dat");
         $fdisplay(channels, "@1");
            val = 16'h2121;
            for(index = 0; index < 60; index = index + 1) 
                begin
                    $fdisplay(channels, "%h", val);
                    val=val+16'h1;
            end

         $fclose(handle);

        /*Read the values in the file 'SRAM.dat' and compare the values with the values that were actually written in the SRAM*/
            $readmemh("SRAM.dat", memory);

         $display("\nContents of memory array");
            mem_idx=23'h1;
         for(index = 0; index < 60; index = index + 1)
                begin
              $display("The Value is:%h and index in hex %h",memory[mem_idx],mem_idx);
                  mem_idx=mem_idx+23'h1;
                end
end
  endmodule
```

Writting the file seems to be ok. However when reading with 'readmemh' I get an error as follows:

> ERROR: Too many words specified in datafile SRAM.dat

And I also do not get the correct values after reading the 23 values:

The Value is:2135 and index in hex 000015
The Value is:2136 and index in hex 000016
The Value is:xxxx and index in hex 000017
The Value is:xxxx and index in hex 000018

Any help on how to read back the correct values and fix the error is appreciated. The simulation was done in Isim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found my mistake. reg [15:0] memory [22:0] should be reg [15:0] memory [60:0], since it refers to total number words in the memory. I though it was interpreted as the bits needed to represent the address.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with writing `reg [15:0] memory [60:0]` but `reg [15:0] memory [0:60]` would be more common.